# Using Google Maps' Geocoding API inside a Java-based Beam Job running on GCP's Dataflow results in "handshake_error"

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-geocoding-api, dataflow

I am trying to use a Java-based Beam job to geocode a bulk of address using Google Maps' Geocoding API. I have a `PCollection` of addresses and a `DoFn` that will take an address, call the Geocoding API and output the result of the call.

My `@Setup` method inside the `DoFn` looks like this:

```
private GeoApiContext context;

@Setup
public void setup() {
        GeoApiContext.Builder contextBuilder = new GeoApiContext.Builder();
        context = contextBuilder
                .apiKey(apiKey)
                .build();
    }
```

Attempting to run the full job on GCP's Dataflow results in the following error, every single time a request is made to the Geocoding API:

```
    Error in process request Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
 [java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128),
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063), 
  java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224),
  okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169), 
  okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41),
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142), 
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117), 
  okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94), 
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142),
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117),
  okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93), 
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142), 
  okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88), 
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142),
  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117), 
  okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221), 
  okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172), 
  okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32), 
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128),
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628), 
  java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)]
```

It seems like there is a networking problem but I do not know how to solve it. My guess is that the workers can't access the public Google APIs, such as the Geocoding API. So I have started playing with the Private Google Access.

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access), they describe the requirements:

- Private Google Access does not automatically enable any API. You must
  enable the Google APIs you need to use via the APIs & services page
  in the Google Cloud Platform Console separately. [Geocoding API is enabled in my project]
- Private Google Access requires a VPC network. Both auto and custom mode VPC networks are supported. Legacy networks are not supported. [I have created a custom VPC network in auto mode]
- Private Google Access only applies to instances that only have internal IP addresses. Enabling or disabling Private Google Access has no effect on instances with external IP addresses. [My Dataflow job is set to not assign public IP address to workers]
- You enable Private Google Access on a subnet-by-subnet basis, either when you create a subnet or by editing the subnet later on. When enabled for a subnet, Private Google Access applies to new and existing VM instances in that subnet that do not have external IP addresses. [The subnetwork that my Dataflow job uses has Private Google Access enabled]
- Private Google Access requires a route to the public IP addresses used by Google APIs and services. The default route usually provides this path. [Default route is present with DEST_RANGE 0.0.0.0/0 and NEXT_HOP default-internet-gateway]

I have also checked and doubel checked the firewall rules since they mention that "*In addition to meeting the routing requirements, firewall rules in your network must allow access from VMs to Google APIs and GCP services.*". I have created a firewall rule that allows egress to the 0.0.0.0/0 address range, which indicates egress can go to any destination.

I literally have no idea what else to do at this point.
Help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: which jdk do you use?

Comment: started with 8, but read something about some SSL errors in that one. now using 10. same error.

Comment: Probably you need update certificates. Note that Google is migrating to new certificates now as mentioned in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139920717

Comment: How does one to that on Dataflow workers?